# MapStruct mapping to unmodifiable model class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dictionary, mapstruct

I am using a model from a library that has multiple constructors and none are parameterless. So compilation fails saying

```
either declare parameterless constructor or annotate the default constructor with an annotation named @Default
```

But as I said, I cannot modify the model as it is from another library. Is there any solution so that I can use mapstruct to map models with multiple constructors none of which are parameterless.

version details

### Dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

### Plugins

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>11</source>
            <target>11</target>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: *So compilation fails saying* - compilation of what?

Comment: compilation of app that uses mapstruct&mapstruct plugin.

Comment: Do you not think that the code is wrong? and if so do you not think it would be of use to show that code to people you are asking to help you?

Comment: This is not code specific problem. A read-only class has multiple constructors each of which has parameter. In this case, mapstruct defaultly cannot map. It expects non parametered constructor or only one parameterized constructor. So asking, if there is a way to achieve mapping in such case.

Answer (score 3):

Mapstruct supports that through [Object Factories](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#object-factories). Check their Documentation.

This is the code that they have there. You can use the Factories to initialize the object however you want to since they do not have default constructors.

```java
public class DtoFactory {

     public CarDto createCarDto() {
         return // ... custom factory logic
     }
}
```

```java
public class EntityFactory {

     public <T extends BaseEntity> T createEntity(@TargetType Class<T> entityClass) {
         return // ... custom factory logic
     }
}
```

```java
@Mapper(uses= { DtoFactory.class, EntityFactory.class } )
public interface CarMapper {

    CarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CarMapper.class );

    CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);

    Car carDtoToCar(CarDto carDto);
}
```

```java
//GENERATED CODE
public class CarMapperImpl implements CarMapper {

    private final DtoFactory dtoFactory = new DtoFactory();

    private final EntityFactory entityFactory = new EntityFactory();

    @Override
    public CarDto carToCarDto(Car car) {
        if ( car == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CarDto carDto = dtoFactory.createCarDto();

        //map properties...

        return carDto;
    }

    @Override
    public Car carDtoToCar(CarDto carDto) {
        if ( carDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Car car = entityFactory.createEntity( Car.class );

        //map properties...

        return car;
    }
}
```

And you can always add your own mapping logic by adding [custom methods](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods).